# How to display Current Location and Nearby Places in windows phone application 8.1 using bing maps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am trying to develop a windows phone 8.1 application.(not silverlight). I need to locate my current location and also nearest location. (i.e geographic points of interest within a given proximity (e.g. 10km) filtered by category, such as "restaurants","petrol bunks","hotels" etc.)

With the help of BingMapsTask we can do it in silverlight applications. So coming to wp8.1 I tried using launch uri. But I cannot get the current location and nearby selected category with this uri

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bingmaps:?lvl=10&where=restaurants", UriKind.Absolute));
```

How to get the current nearby list of places

Answer (score 1):

First get the current Position using "GetGeopositionAsync" function.
Then try it using the coordinates that you received.

Example for the URI: "bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076&lvl=10&where=New%20York"

Also note that the GetGeopositionAsync function would take time so "await" it till you get the result. Use try-catch to check if phone GPS/location is turned ON or not.

Upvote if this works

Cheers

Comment: This GetGeopositionAsync shows the location of the mapcontrol placed in our grid. The Launch Uri navigates to the phone maps. So how to show the nearby locations of the current location

Comment: GetGeopositionAsync gets you the co-ordinate (GeoPosition) which you can show on the map control. it is not something that shows the map.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx